# Error when uploading file to raw resource directory

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I created a raw resource directory and tried to put a folder in it. The folder contains a .opf file and html, css and js files. On my html files I get the following 2 errors. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to add it to an assets directory